# Remapping Left Shift + up arrow to another key

Tags: windows, autohotkey, remapping

Hi guys total AutoHotkey newbie here, I was wondering if any experts could help me with a quick script?

I would like Left Shift & up arrow key to type the question mark key "?"

And Left Shift & down arrow to the "/" key.

Answer (score 1):

[Escape Sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm) says

> When the Send command or Hotstrings are used in their default
> (non-raw) mode, characters such as **{}^!+#** have special meaning. To
> use them literally in these cases, enclose them in braces.
>
> Other characters such as **%;`** must be escaped.

```
LShift + Up arrow
<+Up:: Send {?}
```

or use the [Raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Raw)

```
<+Up:: Send {Raw}?
```

or the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Text) (**recommended**):

```
<+Up:: Send {Text}?
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>▲</kbd> to type the `?` key and <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>▼</kbd> to the `/` key.

*ex. arrow_key_hotkeys.ahk*

```
; Left Shift + Arrow Key UP and Left Shift + Arrow Key DOWN.

<+Up:: Send ?
<+Down:: Send /
```

Where:

- `<+` means <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>
- Up and Down are the names for the UP ( <kbd>▲</kbd> ) and DOWN ( <kbd>▼</kbd> ) arrow keys.

---

*References*

- *[Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) (Official Documentation)*
- *[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) (Official Documentation)*